# How to use SimulationLinkDatum and SimulationNodeDatum in d3

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm having a problem using the SimulationLinkDatum Type. I made two classes Node and Link that implement SimulationNodeDatum and SimulationLinkDatum.  When I go to try and use SimulationLinkDatum typescript says that d.source.x, d.targe.x, etc typescript says that "**Property 'x' does not exist on type 'string | number | Node'.**"

I understand that the SimulationLinkDatum accepts `number | string | <T>` for the source and target node properties and that if you use number or string that it will be mutated into a SimulationNodeDatum. Is this just something that we have to live with or is there a better way of using these interfaces?

Thanks

```
class D3Component {
    private createPathString(d: SimulationLinkDatum<Node>) {
        return 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'L' + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y;
    }
}
class Node implements SimulationNodeDatum {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;
    constructor (public id: number) {}
}

class Link implements SimulationLinkDatum<Node> {
    constructor (public source: Node, public target: Node)  {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly point out, the TypeScript definitions for **d3-force** reflect the approach to mutating the node and link data structures inherent in the actual JS implementation.

Specifically, for the `SimulationLinkDatum<NodeDatum extends SimulationNodeDatum>` interface, the suggested practice is to use a custom type guard, e.g.:

```
function isNodeObject<T>(node: number | string| T): node is T {
    return typeof node !== 'number' && typeof node !== 'string';
}
```

Then the type narrowing of TypeScript can be used in as usual, e.g. in your case above:

```
private createPathString(d: SimulationLinkDatum<Node>) {
  if (isNodeObject(d.source) && isNodeObject(d.target)) {
    return 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'L' + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

While this is the most reusable approach, the following two alternatives may be more suitable in some situations:

(1) If it is known that a given code segment will only be invoked on links that have already been initialized, then one may simply cast `(<SimNode>d.source).x`. Using local variables for the cast node objects may improve downstream readability.

(2) Use the type narrowing directly in an `if`-clause without creating a re-usable custom type guard.

Given the way the interfaces are currently defined, these are the key ways to access the objects in the mutated properties.