# Why do I get an error on `SimulationNodeDatum` when using D3 on Angular 10 for force directed graph?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm using angular v10 and d3 v5 as downloaded and installed using npm. I'm a beginner on angular and d3. I want to create a network graph for my application from which I also want to calculate `in-degree`, `out-degree`, `reciprocity`, etc., but before I did that, I wanted to reproduce force directed graph from d3.js and see if I can understand it and make it work on angular.

When I tried creating it using the tutorial, I get errors. Even after searching on google to resolve this I couldn't find anything useful, or find something that I can understand.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { miserables } from './miserables';

// Services
import { NetworkCategoriesService } from '../services/network-categories.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-network-graph',
  templateUrl: './network-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./network-graph.component.css']
})

export class NetworkGraphComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
  private width: number;
  private height: number;
  private x: any;
  private y: any;
  private svg: any;
  private data: any;
  private simulation: any;
  private color: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.createSvg();
    //this.createNetwork();
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.width = 960 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = 500 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(this.width / 2, this.height / 2));

    this.render(miserables);
  }

  private createSvg(): void {

    this.svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height);

  }
}
```

But when I compile, I always get the following error. How do I fix it? And I see some tutorials online which does the same exact thing as below and theirs seem to work.

```
ERROR in src/app/network/network-graph.component.ts:44:64 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'SimulationNodeDatum'.

44       .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }))
                                                                  ~~
src/app/network/network-graph.component.ts:48:10 - error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'NetworkGraphComponent'.

48     this.render(miserables);
            ~~~~~~
```

Comment: I would recommend installing @types/d3 package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3) and starting to work with actual types.

Comment: Yes, I have that installed also.

Comment: Well, both errors are straightforward, in the second one you are calling render method even though your component doesn't have that method, and first one implies that id is not a property of the 'd' variable passed to your callback by d3. You should fully utilize TS by avoiding 'any' usage, that is what I am saying, makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: `render` is just something I was trying looking at the tutorial. But my concerned is mostly with `SimulationNodeDatum`. I'm doing exactly what other's are doing in the tutorial and examples, but I keep getting this error. I'm not sure what type the simulation would be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696302/how-to-use-simulationlinkdatum-and-simulationnodedatum-in-d3 might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use arrow function instead of anonymous function like this:

```
 .force("link", d3.forceLink().id((d: any) => d.id).strength(0.015))
```

this solved my problem.